# PostGres select from table with object

Tags: postgresql

In postgres I have a table named info that has columns like so:

id, type, account, data

where data is a JSON object and has other fields on it like user_id, nickname, location.

If I wanted to do something like `select * from info where data.nickame = 'SomeNickname';`

How would I do that?

Comment: By reading the docs [JSON operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Answer (score 1):

For `json`, you'll need [an operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
select * from info where data->>'nickname'              = 'SomeNickname';
select * from info where data#>>array['nickname']       = 'SomeNickname';
select * from info where data#>>'{nickname}'            = 'SomeNickname';
select * from info where (data->'nickname')::text       = '"SomeNickname"';
select * from info where (data#>'{nickname}')::text     = '"SomeNickname"';
select * from info where (data#>array['nickname'])::text= '"SomeNickname"';
```

[`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING) can also be subscripted using brackets and [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH):

```sql
select * from info where (data::jsonb)['nickname'] = '"SomeNickname"';
select * from info where data::jsonb @@ '$.nickname=="SomeNickname"';
select * from info where jsonb_path_match(data::jsonb,'$.nickname=="SomeNickname"');
```

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OeUNl9zr)